# Need to update a part of page when a new entry is entered

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm trying to create a site where users can post things they are looking for.

On the home page of the site I want to have a section that is 'live'. That basically means it updates every time a new entry is posted, so that anyone viewing the page can have a live view of all the posts.

I'm doing the site using GlassFish 3 and JSF 2.0. I'm learning JSF and Java EE right now, so a solution using those would be the best as it's what I know now. But, I'm willing to learn whatever you can suggest.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use polling. Look at [Richfaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces/) component library and the [a4j:poll](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Actions.html#sect-Component_Reference-Actions-a4jpoll) component. At a specific time frame an `ajax` call is made to the server to return the latest posts. Then only the needed part of your page is updated.

[Link](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_poll.html) to developer's guide.

A more complex solution is to use [a4j:push](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Actions.html#sect-Component_Reference-a4jpush-Handling_a_push_notification) but use it, if you really need it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Petar's answer.  Using polling will make the page query the server at intervals to refresh itself.
You can do some polling with primefaces too : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/poll.jsf

Example from the link above :

```xml
<h:form id="form">  
    <h:outputText id="txt_count" value="#{counterBean.count}" />  

    <p:poll interval="3"   
            listener="#{counterBean.increment}" update="txt_count" />  
</h:form>
```

As you can see, the "increment()" method of "counterBean" will be called at each 3 seconds, and  each time, the txt_count text will be updated to the new value.